# Looking for an expansion on the AP sum formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

If I have an x where x starts at x=5, and each step adds 10, so that x1=5, x2=15, x3=25, etc...so that if there were 3 steps the answer would be 5+15+25=45.

This is most properly answered by https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sum-of-1-to-50/answer/Arunabh-Kashyap-1 , in this case the answer is S=n/2{2a+(n−1)d where n=number of steps, d=amount increased, and a is the start point, so:

100/2*(2*5+(100-1)*10)=50000

I was taught it as a shortened formula of average of first number and last number (5 and 995, for an average of 500) times the number of steps. (500*100=50000)

Now, that works for a set additive expansion, but if I use a multiplier instead of an addition, I find it stops working.

If I start at x=5 and multiply each step by 2, so that x1=5, x2=10, x3=20, at x3 the sum is 5+10+20=35

At 100 steps the actual answer to 3 significant digits is 6.34E+30. Using my shortened formula above, I get 1.58E+32. I have no idea how to modify the original formula.

How can I modify this as a *general* formula to figure out large stepped problems like this with generic starting points and for various multiplicative values? Also, if I need to figure out the value for the last step, how can I do that without using a spreadsheet? :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could you list out a few terms of the sequence whose sum you want to find? As the question is currently written, it’s unclear as to what kind of sequence you’re referring to.

Comment: I have changed the text to clarify my example problem Heisenberg :)

Comment: I found a formula for a sum that combies both an arithmatic and a geometric sequence sums, since you've said you wanted to expand the arithmatic series sum formula, could this be what you're refering to? An arithmetico geometric sequence sums formula? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence

Comment: Mark's answer is exactly what I was looking for, someone please upvote it for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a [geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452749/looking-for-an-expansion-on-the-ap-sum-formula), and there's a well-known general summation formula:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n ar^k = a(\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r})$$

So if you have a starting value $a=5$, and multiplier $r=2$, the sum of the first 100 terms ($n=99$) is $5\frac{1-2^{100}}{1-2} \approx 6.338253 \times 10^{30} $

Comment: Figuring stuff out from scratch is so fun, but a formula is so much better. Thank you, I knew I wasn't the first person to try to figure this out.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer as correct, but I apparently don't have enough reputation to, sorry.